# performing multiple string operations on a pandas Series/DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to perform several operations on a particular Series. Is there a way to chain them without continually writing `.str`? ie if my series is called `s` and i want to do

```
s.str.replace("hi", "bye").str.strip().str.lower()
```

Is that the right way to do things? Seems verbose relative to R so I thought maybe there was a better syntax for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### comprehension

Yes (sorta).  Use a comprehension

```
[x.replace('hi', 'bye').strip().lower() for x in s]
```

Wrap that up into a series again.

```
pd.Series([x.replace('hi', 'bye').strip().lower() for x in s], s.index)
```

---

### `map`

```
s.map(lambda x: x.replace('hi', 'bye').strip().lower())
```

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that vectorized string operations don't always outperform regular Python loops. Even when they do, the difference is not that much. Pandas handles labels/NaNs for you though.

Comment: @piRSquared  side q: when you iterate over s in the list comp, the iterator returns each row one at a time?

Comment: The way you wrote `s` implies that it is a `Series`.  In that case, yes, the comprehension iterates one element of the series' values at a time.

Comment: @piRSquared I am late but is there more efficient way to do the same ?